# not able to read content pdf which is open in url

Tags: java, selenium, pdfbox

i want to read a content of the pdf which is open in url:-https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=4aeea5b52d6e48a7beca13a992540a66&key=7b6184962856e016a5cdfcb3e27c7c30b34b5caaa6607d7d4e408f4b2ebf9dfd

```
try {
        String pdfContent = readPdfContent(perfecturl);
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("Test Kumar"));
        Assert.assertTrue(pdfContent.contains("XXXXX"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static  String readPdfContent(String url) throws IOException {
    
    URL pdfUrl = new URL(url);
    InputStream in = pdfUrl.openStream();
    BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(bf);
    int numberOfPages = getPageCount(doc);
    System.out.println("The total number of pages "+numberOfPages);
    String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
    doc.close();

return content;
```

}

```
public static int getPageCount(PDDocument doc) {
//get the total number of pages in the pdf document
int pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages();
return pageCount;
```

}

it throws me exception:-

```
Error: End-of-File, expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1093)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2580)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2551)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1228)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1128)
```

pdfbox not able to read the pdf and this url is valid PDF so can any one helep me to get this resolve.

Comment: Likely empty or not PDF. Try saving the content in a file and then open it with NOTEPAD++ to see what's in it. Use `Files.copy()`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: I tried to enter your URL into the browser. It gets a HTML page. This HTML page includes several Javascript files. You'd need to find out which one of these shows the PDF / what happens when one clicks the download button.

Comment: i found that <script type="text/javascript" src="main.8b64ac6a2d5919ed6273.js"></script> but how can i verify text in that because its coming through scripts and one click is download the file but that not include i want to verify text contain in that..

Comment: As I wrote, you need to find out where the PDF comes from. Alternatively, use the API of that website, see here: http://ws.careerbuilder.com/schemas/ .